# Showing html elements only if available

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm trying to fill popups of a Leaflet JS Map with Content from a csv table. The popup is filled with html. It perfectly fits my needs. The only problem I have is that not every popup has a image available, but every popup depends on the same html code shown below:

```
popUp = "<h2>"+feature.properties.Name+"</h2>" +
        "<img src='"+ feature.properties.picturelink +"'width='300'</img>" +"<br>"+"<br>"+
        "<h4>"+feature.properties.description+"<br>"
```

If there's no image available, a place holder is shown:
[placeholder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCRe0.png)

Is there a way to only show actual images and to hide the placeholder if there is none?

Answer (score 0):

You can add `onerror` to the image to hide it if broken.

```
onerror="this.style.display='none'"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest:

```
// here we're using a template literal which allows us to interpolate
// JavaScript variables (wrapped in the ${...}) directly into the string
// which avoids having to concatenate strings; this also allows new-lines
// within the string itself:
let popUp = `<h2>${feature.properties.Name}</h2>
             <img src="${feature.properties.picturelink}"
                  width="300"
                  // here we use a conditional/ternary operator,
                  // if the feature.properties.picturelink property
                  // is falsey then the style of the <img> is set
                  // to display: none; otherwise - if the property
                  // is truthy - it's set to display: auto:
                  style="${ feature.properties.picturelink ? 'auto' : 'none' }">
             <br><br>
             <h4>${feature.properties.description}</h4>`;
```

References:

- [Conditional (Ternary) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).
- [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).